# How to type ‘#’ instead of ‘£’ in Vim in a UK Ubuntu VM?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, vmware

My Ubuntu image (running on VMware) is generated in the UK. When I type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, I get a UK pound sign `£` instead of `#`.

How can I change that?

Comment: Did you tried to change the keyboard configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it with `setxkbmap`

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```